# How to prevent Cross-Side Scripting in JQuery .append() command

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have serval `.append()` code inside of my ajax call in order to display the contents in my dropdown list. However,  when I test my code in the security code test application, it tells me all the area I worte `.append()` command have potential risk to be XSSed. Here's my Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "home/getValue",
                data: { "dropdownId": dropdownID },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        $("#dropdownlist").append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).attr("placeholder", option.placeholder).html(option.name));

                    });//end each function
                },//end success
```

I tried some solutions such as "never add new attribute inside of '<>' tag" or " use Unicode like U+003C or \u003c instead of '<' ", but the problem still exists.
My situation is that I need at least 3 attributes or more in my project(id,name, something else in string type) in order to get next step, so I have to keep those parameters inside of the `<option>`. But if I can't use `.append()` in this way, I don't know how to dynamically generate those `<option>`s with these values inside.

Anyone has better idea how to solve this?

Thank you

Kevin

Comment: Can you use `.text` instead of `.html`, or do you really need to include foramtting?

Comment: Yes, I surely can. I tried that but still couldn't pass the XSS verification in the security application. Formatting is not that important.

Comment: Does it offer an explanation of *why* it thinks there is an XSS vulnerability, even with `text()`? The use of `.html()` is the only code-injection possibility I see here. What if you eliminate all use of `option` and just do `.append($('<option></option>'));`? What if you only set `val`?

Comment: Kinda hard to overcome a vulnerability if you don't know what the vulnerability is.

Comment: Always a good read from the OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)  - maybe you can reevaluate then if that's really a XXS vulnerability here

Comment: Hi @apsillers, The problem is coming from those `.val()`, `.html()`, `.attr()` or whatever suffix you named after `.append()`. I have a solution and I just wrote it below. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so I came down a solution that can prevent Cross-side Scripting,not sure it can apply to all situations but at least I passed security verification using this method. I wrote here down to give a clue if somebody's having the same/similar issue as I had.

```
//declare some vars
var yourvalue = //somevalue;
var yourtitle = //sometitle;
var yourName = //somename;
```

Instead of writing:

```
$("#SomethingID").append($('<option></option>').val(yourvalue).attr('placeholder',yourtitle).html(yourName));
```

Do this:

```
$("#SomethingID").append("<option value= '"+ yourvalue +"' placeholder= '"+ yourtitle +"'>"+ yourhtml +"</option>";
```

It seems like making this `.append()` code more html-like can prevent Cross-side scripting. It's called Html escaping or attribute escaping or something like that, but here is the reference you can check out: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: This seems absolutely backward to me. Consider the case where `yourvalue` is the string `foo'></option><img onerror='alert("bad stuff")'><option value='bar`. The first case there is no vulnerability; in the second case, there **is** a vulnerability. This change appears to **add new vulnerabilities** where there didn't exist before, and it doesn't fix the old one. What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm totally right here with ya, I was having the exact same thought as you wrote here. But my goal is just to pass that code scan and do next step. My company uses Veracode.com as security code scan engine. I don't think this solution would be the most correct one, I'll keep looking other better solutions.

Comment: @QIWENHU: Were you able to fix the veracode flaw for the above issue?. If so, can you please share your fix details to the community